# Existence of limit point of infinite set satisfying T1 axiom

Tags: general-topology

It a set A is satisfying T1 axiom, then finite subset of A is closed in A

Assume that A is infinite and let finite point subset of A as {a1, a2, a3, ... , an}

Since it is finite, it is closed in A.

I couldn't advance more from this stage..

Does A have no limit points?

Answer (score 0):

In a $T_1$ space each one-point set is closed, so each finite set is closed too being a finite union of closed sets.